# Is it possible to set up jupyter notebook so that it is usable after suspend/sleep

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, suspend

I use Jupyter notebook a lot on my laptop. It all works well until I suspend/sleep the laptop. When the laptop wakes up the  notebooks are no longer usable. I guess  this is because the kernel hasn't been revived?

Is it possible to set up Jupyter notebook so that it is usable after suspend/sleep?

Comment: Use `caffeinate` command not to make your laptop sleep

Comment: @bigbounty I would like it to sleep sometimes.

Comment: Which operation system you are on? Never noticed this with my notebooks on windows / mac

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 is the OS

Comment: @Anush What do you mean by "no longer usable"? Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, suspend/restart works without problem for Jupyer notebooks.